# Access to children in a self reference tree view in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, treeview

I have build a self reference hierarchy using tree view in wpf.

```
<telerik:RadTreeView Name="selfReferenceTree" Grid.Column="1" IsTriStateMode="True"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource HierarchyConverter}}"
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SelfRefTemplate}">
</telerik:RadTreeView>

<local:TreeViewHiearchyConverter x:Key="HierarchyConverter" />
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="SelfRefTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource HierarchyConverter}}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="stack">
           <CheckBox Name="check" Content="{Binding Code}" Click="checkBox_click"></CheckBox>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

For the converter, he take root item and return his children.

In my c# code, I want to select a child `RadTreeViewItem`. I used

```
RadTreeViewItem item = selfReferenceTree.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(MyEntity) as RadTreeViewItem;
```

But it returns a null value. It select only root items. I want to cast child to RadTreeViewItem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Items` property on the `RadTreeView` to get your `RadTreeViewItem`:

```
var myEntity = selfReferenceTree.Items.Cast<RadTreeViewItem>.FirstOrDefault(rtvi => rvti == MyEntity);
```